# how can i check the quantity from text box if it is higher or lower than the quantity in database column if the category is not "Dish"? vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Im having a problem in my code how will I check the value from textbox if it is higher or lower than the value in my database?
here is my code:

```vb
Public Sub additem()
    Dim str As String
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Try
    str = "select * from tbl_items where ItemName = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
    con.Open()
    With cmd
        .CommandText = str
        .Connection = con

    End With
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            Dim qty As String = dr("quantity")
            Dim ctgy1 As String = dr("category")
            If quantity.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Please Add Quantity or Number of Order(s)!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Quantity")
            ElseIf ctgy1 IsNot "Dish" Then
                If TextBox1.Text > qty Then
                    MsgBox("Insufficient Stock!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Quantity")
                Else
                    Dim price As Decimal = dr("Price")
                    Dim itemcode As String = dr("ItemName")
                    Dim ctgy As String = dr("category")
                    Dim desc As String = dr("description")
                    totalprice = Val(quantity.Text) * price
                    CashRegister.BunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows.Add(itemcode, price, quantity.Text, totalprice, ctgy, desc)
                    CashRegister.BunifuCustomDataGrid2.Columns("category").Visible = False

                    con.Close()
                    UpdateDecreaseQuantity()
                    loadtables()
                    dr.Close()
                    Me.Close()

                End If
            Else
                Dim price As Decimal = dr("Price")
                Dim itemcode As String = dr("ItemName")
                Dim ctgy As String = dr("category")
                Dim desc As String = dr("description")
                totalprice = Val(quantity.Text) * price
                CashRegister.BunifuCustomDataGrid2.Rows.Add(itemcode, price, quantity.Text, totalprice, ctgy, desc)
                CashRegister.BunifuCustomDataGrid2.Columns("category").Visible = False

                con.Close()
                UpdateDecreaseQuantity()
                loadtables()
                dr.Close()
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End While


    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

    End Try

End Sub
```

what i want to happen is if the category is not equal to Dish or Dessert it will check the quantity input in the textbox and compare to the quantity in the  database. can anyone help me on this one? thank you!

Comment: For future reference the TITLE of your thread should be written like a title. It's not supposed to be a full explanation or follow correct sentence structure. It should be generic and concise.  You should then include ALL the details in the question.  For instance, any reference to "Dish" is irrelevant in the title but should be included in the question specifically. For instance: "Compare TextBox contents to database column value based on other database column value".  The specifics of how you want to compare and what values to use belong in the question, not the title.

Comment: First thing to do is to learn how to use SQL Parameters in queries.  Gluing strings together is dangerous, tedious and very error prone which i swhy it has not been the correct way for many many years now.  Then look into how to compare strings `ElseIf ctgy1 IsNot "Dish"` is probably not what you want